# Objective-C: Is there any trick to avoid casting of NSArray objects?

Tags: objective-c, foundation

Very often I find myself casting objects in NSArray to my types, when I want to access their specific properties with dot notation (instead of getter) without creating an extra variable.

Is there any cool feature or trick to tell objective-c which one class of objects I'm going to store to NSArray, so that compiler will assume objects in an array to be my type, not an id?

Comment: You could just not use dot syntax and use normal method-invocation syntax: `[[myArray objectAtIndex:i] property]` (or `setProperty:...`).

Comment: Sure, Im aware of calling the getter, just I'm curious)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean you're doing things like:

```
x = ((MyClass *)[myArray objectAtIndex:2]).property1;
```

You can just split it into two lines to be easier to read:

```
MyClass *myObject = [myArray objectAtIndex:2]
x = myObject.property1;
```

If you're really set on the first case, you could make a category on `NSArray` that has an accessor for your type:

```
@implementation NSArray (MyCategory)

- (MyClass *)myClassObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
   return [self objectAtIndex:index];
}

@end
```

And then you can use it like you want:

```
x = [myArray myClassObjectAtIndex:2].property1;
```

Comment: +1 - that's a great trick - I often forget to take advantage of categories in obj-c.

Comment: Ya, but I somehow got used to have very long lines when coding in obj-c. Nice way with category, and is there any preprocessor directives to tell compiler to treat [] at the call to myClassObjectAtIndex?

Comment: Hmm - not as far as I know.

Comment: actually there is. `arr[0]` gets translated at compile time to `[arr objectAtIndexedSubscript:0];` so you technically can override it in a category/subclass. It seems like a terrible idea though.

Comment: I almost regret for having mentioned that, so let me state this as clear as I can: ***you don't wan't to subclass a `NSArray`***.

Comment: Cool, indeed, but it's fun. Hope syntax analyser is smart to look at the objectAtIndexSubsript return type)

Why subclassing an NSArray is a bad idea?

Comment: Because it works well as it is and there's a few non-trivial details that you have to consider when subclassing a class cluster (`NSArray` is not a concrete class). Read [this](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-03-12-subclassing-class-clusters.html) and carefully consider whether you want to go through all that hassle just for saving a few keystrokes.

Comment: So please, don't do it. Subclassing `NSArray` is shooting a fly with a bazooka, and overriding `objectAtIndexSubscript:` in a category will likely break every other array in your code base.

Comment: Ya) Alright alright, I promise, I won't do that, but it's always good to kill the curiosity)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use properties in this situation. You can't say

```
arr[ix].myProperty
```

But you can always say

```
[arr[ix] myProperty]
```

Comment: Sure, Im aware of calling the getter, just have a programming habbit of using .dot notation, so I'm asking just for the matter of style)

Comment: The matter of style is break the dot notation habit. Or just keep casting.... `arr[ix]` is an `id` so you can send any message to it. But properties don't work that way (because of how they are pasted onto the language as an afterthought).

Comment: Yeah, I always keep casting, ya, smalltalk has no been designed with a .dot notation in mind, so it makes perfect sense to use dot notation less.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly answering to your question, no.

There's no language support for indicating the parametric type of a collection, i.e. something like `NSArray<MyClass>`.

That said, you can find workarounds for avoiding an explicit cast.

Since the returned object is of type `id` you can invoke any - existing - method on it and the compiler won't raise an eyebrow, unless you're using dot-syntax notation, which has stricter compiler checks.

So for instance

```
NSString * name = [people[0] firstName];
```

works flawlessly without a cast, whereas

```
NSString * name = people[0].firstName;
```

doesn't.